# Arduino Raspberry RadioHead node sends sensor data with sendtowait (ReliableDatagram) raspberry receives but node gets no ack

Tags: library

I have a configuration like following:
An Arduino and a raspberry both running with RadioHead library
Arduino with sensor sends data to a raspberry gateway using RHReliableDatagram with the sendtoWait method. Raspberry receives data and processes it with success. But Arduino receives no ack from raspberry. Have you any hint what the problem could be?

Arduino code

```
#include <RH_RF95.h>
#include <RHReliableDatagram.h>
#include <CayenneLPP.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// START CONFIGURATION
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* COMMENT FOR PRODUCTION USE */
#define DEBUG

// SELECT FREQUENCY APPROPRIATE TO YOUR COUNTRY
#define RF_FREQUENCY 868.0

// CHANGE HERE THE NODE ADDRESS 
#define SERVER_ADDRESS 2
// GIVE EACH NODE A UNIQUE ID
#define NODE_ADDR 31

/* SELECT THE USED SENSOR TYPE */
// ONLY ONE OF THE FOLLOWING MUST BE DEFINED, IF ANY
#define ADAFRUIT_SI7021
//#define ADAFRUIT_SHT31

/* UNCOMMENT IF USING OLED DISPLAY */
//#define OLED
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CONFIGURATION
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifdef ADAFRUIT_SI7021
#include <Adafruit_Si7021.h>
#elif defined ADAFRUIT_SHT31
#include <Adafruit_SHT31.h>
#endif

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF95 rf95;
//RH_RF95 rf95(5, 2); // Rocket Scream Mini Ultra Pro with the RFM95W
//RH_RF95 rf95(8, 3); // Adafruit Feather M0 with RFM95 

// Class to manage message delivery and receipt, using the driver declared above
RHReliableDatagram manager(rf95, NODE_ADDR);

CayenneLPP lpp(51);

#ifdef ADAFRUIT_SI7021
Adafruit_Si7021 si7021 = Adafruit_Si7021();
#elif defined ADAFRUIT_SHT31
Adafruit_SHT31 sht31 = Adafruit_SHT31();
#endif

const long InternalReferenceVoltage = 1062;  // Adjust this value to your board's specific internal BG voltage

int donePin = 4;
#ifdef ADAFRUIT_SI7021 || ADAFRUIT_SHT31
double tmp;
double hum;
#endif
double bat;
char msg[128];

// Need this on Arduino Zero with SerialUSB port (eg RocketScream Mini Ultra Pro)
//#define Serial SerialUSB

char *ftoa(char *a, double f, int precision)
{
 long p[] = {0,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000};

 char *ret = a;
 long heiltal = (long)f;
 itoa(heiltal, a, 10);
 while (*a != '\0') a++;
 *a++ = '.';
 long desimal = abs((long)((f - heiltal) * p[precision]));
 if (desimal < p[precision-1]) {
  *a++ = '0';
 }  
 itoa(desimal, a, 10);
 return ret;
}

//read internal voltage
double readVcc() {
  long result;
  // Read 1.1V reference against AVcc
  ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
  delay(2); // Wait for Vref to settle
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC); // Convert
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA, ADSC));
  result = ADCL;
  result |= ADCH << 8;
  result = 1126400L / result; // Back-calculate AVcc in mV
  return double(result) / 1000;
}

void setup() 
{
  // Rocket Scream Mini Ultra Pro with the RFM95W only:
  // Ensure serial flash is not interfering with radio communication on SPI bus
//  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
//  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);

#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Started");
#endif

  pinMode(donePin, OUTPUT);

#ifdef ADAFRUIT_SI7021
  if (!si7021.begin()) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Did not find Si7021 sensor!");
#endif
    while (true);
  }
#elif defined ADAFRUIT_SHT31
  if (!sht31.begin(0x44)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Did not find Si7021 sensor!");
#endif
    while (true);
  }
#endif

  if (!rf95.init())
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("init failed");
#endif

  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, 13dBm, Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on
  rf95.setFrequency(RF_FREQUENCY);
  rf95.setModeTx();
  rf95.setTxPower(14, false); // values between 5 to 23
  manager.setThisAddress(NODE_ADDR);
  manager.setHeaderFrom(NODE_ADDR);
}

void loop()
{

#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("Sending to gateway ");
  Serial.println(SERVER_ADDRESS);
#endif

  int i = 0;
  lpp.reset();

#ifdef ADAFRUIT_SI7021
  tmp = si7021.readTemperature();
  lpp.addTemperature(1, tmp);
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("Temperature Si7021: ");
  Serial.println(tmp);
#endif
  hum = si7021.readHumidity();
  lpp.addRelativeHumidity(2, hum);
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("Humidity Si7021: ");
  Serial.println(hum);
#endif
#elif defined ADAFRUIT_SHT31
  tmp = sht31.readTemperature();
  lpp.addTemperature(1, tmp);
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("Temperature SHT31: ");
  Serial.println(tmp);
#endif
  hum = sht31.readHumidity();
  lpp.addRelativeHumidity(2, hum);
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("Humidity SHT31: ");
  Serial.println(hum);
#endif
#endif

  bat = readVcc();
  if (!isnan(bat)) 
  {
    lpp.addVoltage(3, bat);
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.print("Voltage: ");
    Serial.println(bat);
#endif
  }

#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.print("Send data: ");
#endif

//  if (manager.sendtoWaitTimeout(lpp.getBuffer(), lpp.getSize(), SERVER_ADDRESS))
  if (manager.sendtoWait(lpp.getBuffer(), lpp.getSize(), SERVER_ADDRESS))
  {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("OK");
#endif
  }
  else
  {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Failed (no reply, is server running)?");
#endif
  }

  digitalWrite(donePin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(donePin, HIGH);

#ifdef DEBUG
  delay(10000);
#endif
}
```

Raspberry Code:

```
// rf95_server.cpp
//
// Example program showing how to use RH_RF95 on Raspberry Pi
// Uses the bcm2835 library to access the GPIO pins to drive the RFM95 module
// Requires bcm2835 library to be already installed
// http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/
// Use the Makefile in this directory:
// cd example/raspi/rf95
// make
// sudo ./rf95_server
//
// Contributed by Charles-Henri Hallard based on sample RH_NRF24 by Mike Poublon

#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "RadioHead/RH_RF69.h"
#include "RadioHead/RH_RF95.h"
#include "RadioHead/RHReliableDatagram.h"

#include <MQTTClient.h>
#include "SimpleIni/SimpleIni.h"

// define hardware used change to fit your need
// Uncomment the board you have, if not listed
// uncommment custom board and set wiring tin custom section

// LoRasPi board
// see https://github.com/hallard/LoRasPI
//#define BOARD_LORASPI

// iC880A and LinkLab Lora Gateway Shield (if RF module plugged into)
// see https://github.com/ch2i/iC880A-Raspberry-PI
//#define BOARD_IC880A_PLATE

// Raspberri PI Lora Gateway for multiple modules
// see https://github.com/hallard/RPI-Lora-Gateway
//#define BOARD_PI_LORA_GATEWAY

// Dragino Raspberry PI hat
// see https://github.com/dragino/Lora
#define BOARD_DRAGINO_PIHAT

// Now we include RasPi_Boards.h so this will expose defined
// constants with CS/IRQ/RESET/on board LED pins definition
#include "../RasPiBoards.h"

// Our RFM95 Configuration
#define RF_FREQUENCY  868.00
//#define RF_NODE_ID    1  replaced by gateway_id in rf95_server.ini

// Create an instance of a driver
RH_RF95 rf95(RF_CS_PIN, RF_IRQ_PIN);
//RH_RF95 rf95(RF_CS_PIN);

// Ini file
CSimpleIniA ini;

// Our MQTT Client Configuration
#define TIMEOUT 10000L
int rc;

//Flag for Ctrl-C
volatile sig_atomic_t force_exit = false;

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
  printf("\n%s Break received, exiting!\n", __BASEFILE__);
  force_exit=true;
}

int reconnect(MQTTClient client, const char* dest_addr, MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts)
{
  while (!MQTTClient_isConnected(client))
  {
    printf("Connect to MQTT broker on %s\n", dest_addr);
    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) == MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS) 
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect to MQTT broker: %d\n", rc);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, ".");
        delay(500);
      }
      fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

//Main Function
int main (int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
  unsigned long led_blink = 0;

  signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
  printf( "Starting %s\n", __BASEFILE__);

  ini.SetUnicode();
  if (ini.LoadFile("rf95_server.ini") < 0) {
    printf("Error occurred while trying to open ini file. Please provide a valid ini file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Content of rf95_server.ini\n");
  const char *project = ini.GetValue("common", "project", NULL);
  printf("project=%s\n", project);
  const char *dest_addr = ini.GetValue("common", "dest_addr", NULL);
  printf("dest_addr=%s\n", dest_addr);
  const char *client_id = ini.GetValue("common", "client_id", NULL);
  printf("client_id=%s\n\n", client_id);
  const char *gateway_id = ini.GetValue("common", "gateway_id", NULL);
  printf("gateway_id=%s\n\n", gateway_id);

  if (!bcm2835_init()) {
    fprintf( stderr, "%s bcm2835_init() Failed\n\n", __BASEFILE__ );
    return 1;
  }

  printf( "RF95 CS=GPIO%d", RF_CS_PIN);

#ifdef RF_LED_PIN
  pinMode(RF_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RF_LED_PIN, HIGH );
#endif

#ifdef RF_IRQ_PIN
  printf( ", IRQ=GPIO%d", RF_IRQ_PIN );
  // IRQ Pin input/pull down
  pinMode(RF_IRQ_PIN, INPUT);
  bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(RF_IRQ_PIN, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_DOWN);
  // Now we can enable Rising edge detection
  bcm2835_gpio_ren(RF_IRQ_PIN);
#endif

#ifdef RF_RST_PIN
  printf( ", RST=GPIO%d", RF_RST_PIN );
  // Pulse a reset on module
  pinMode(RF_RST_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RF_RST_PIN, LOW );
  bcm2835_delay(150);
  digitalWrite(RF_RST_PIN, HIGH );
  bcm2835_delay(100);
#endif

#ifdef RF_LED_PIN
  printf( ", LED=GPIO%d", RF_LED_PIN );
  digitalWrite(RF_LED_PIN, LOW );
#endif

  printf( " OK NodeID=%d @ %3.2fMHz\n", *gateway_id, RF_FREQUENCY );

  MQTTClient client;
  MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
  MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
  MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
  char topic[128];

  printf("Create MQTT client\n");
  if ((MQTTClient_create(&client, dest_addr, client_id, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Creation of MQTT client failed \n");
    return 1;
  }
  conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
  conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
  reconnect(client, dest_addr, conn_opts);

  printf("Init RF95 module");
  RHReliableDatagram manager(rf95, *gateway_id);
  if (!manager.init()) {
    fprintf( stderr, "\nRF95 module init failed, Please verify wiring/module\n" );
  } else {
    // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, 13dBm, Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on

    // The default transmitter power is 13dBm, using PA_BOOST.
    // If you are using RFM95/96/97/98 modules which uses the PA_BOOST transmitter pin, then 
    // you can set transmitter powers from 5 to 23 dBm:
    //  driver.setTxPower(23, false);
    // If you are using Modtronix inAir4 or inAir9,or any other module which uses the
    // transmitter RFO pins and not the PA_BOOST pins
    // then you can configure the power transmitter power for -1 to 14 dBm and with useRFO true. 
    // Failure to do that will result in extremely low transmit powers.
    // rf95.setTxPower(14, true);


    // RF95 Modules don't have RFO pin connected, so just use PA_BOOST
    // check your country max power useable, in EU it's +14dB
    rf95.setTxPower(14, false);

    // You can optionally require this module to wait until Channel Activity
    // Detection shows no activity on the channel before transmitting by setting
    // the CAD timeout to non-zero:
    //rf95.setCADTimeout(10000);

    // Adjust Frequency
    printf("set lora frequency to %d", RF_FREQUENCY);
    rf95.setFrequency(RF_FREQUENCY);

    // If we need to send something
    manager.setThisAddress(*gateway_id);
    manager.setHeaderFrom(*gateway_id);

    // Be sure to grab all node packet
    // we're sniffing to display, it's a demo
    rf95.setPromiscuous(true);

    // We're ready to listen for incoming message
    printf("set receive mode");
    rf95.setModeRx();

    //Begin the main body of code
    while (!force_exit) {

#ifdef RF_IRQ_PIN
      // We have a IRQ pin ,pool it instead reading
      // Modules IRQ registers from SPI in each loop

      // Rising edge fired ?
      if (bcm2835_gpio_eds(RF_IRQ_PIN)) {
        // Now clear the eds flag by setting it to 1
        bcm2835_gpio_set_eds(RF_IRQ_PIN);
        //printf("Packet Received, Rising event detect for pin GPIO%d\n", RF_IRQ_PIN);
#endif

        printf( "Listening...\n" );

        if (rf95.available()) {
#ifdef RF_LED_PIN
          led_blink = millis();
          digitalWrite(RF_LED_PIN, HIGH);
#endif
          // Should be a message for us now
          uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
          uint8_t len  = sizeof(buf);
          uint16_t from = manager.headerFrom();
          uint8_t to   = manager.headerTo();
          uint8_t id   = manager.headerId();
          uint8_t flags= manager.headerFlags();;
          int8_t rssi  = rf95.lastRssi();

          if (manager.recvfromAck(buf, &len)) {
            printf("Packet[%02d] #%d => #%d %ddB:\n", len, from, to, rssi);
            printbuffer(buf, len);
            printf("\n");

            pubmsg.payload = &buf;
            pubmsg.payloadlen = len;
            pubmsg.qos = 2;
            pubmsg.retained = 0;
            sprintf(topic, "%s/%s/%d", project, client_id, from);

            reconnect(client, dest_addr, conn_opts);
            if ((rc = MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, topic, &pubmsg, &token)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Publish failed: %d\n", rc);
              force_exit = 1;
            } else {
              if ((rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT)) == MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS) {
                printf("Message with token %d delivered successfully\n", token);
              }
            }
          } else {
            Serial.print("receive failed\n");
          }
        }

#ifdef RF_IRQ_PIN
      }
#endif

#ifdef RF_LED_PIN
      // Led blink timer expiration ?
      if (led_blink && millis()-led_blink>200) {
        led_blink = 0;
        digitalWrite(RF_LED_PIN, LOW);
      }
#endif
      // Let OS doing other tasks
      // For timed critical appliation you can reduce or delete
      // this delay, but this will charge CPU usage, take care and monitor
      bcm2835_delay(5);
    }
  }
  MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
  MQTTClient_destroy(&client);

#ifdef RF_LED_PIN
  digitalWrite(RF_LED_PIN, LOW );
#endif
  printf( "\n%s ending\n", __BASEFILE__ );
  bcm2835_gpio_clr_ren(RF_IRQ_PIN);
  bcm2835_close();
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you!
Regards
Christian